# How to populate dropdownlist in edit mode ASP.NET MVC (C#) without using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I'm not a fan of using Entity Framework, so I want to accomplish is that when I edit here

[Position Index list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W89fY.png)

I want to display the department value to dropdownlist, and when the user select the dropdown it will load all the list from database.

Here is my controller code in edit:

```
//GET data from database
public ActionResult UpdatePos(int pid)
{
            DepartmentList posmodel = new DepartmentList();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (MySqlConnection mysqlcon = new MySqlConnection(conn))
            {
                mysqlcon.Open();
                string qry = "SELECT id,position,department FROM positions WHERE id = @pid";
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(qry, mysqlcon);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", pid);
                da.Fill(dt);
            }

            if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                //id and posistion is showing in my view
                posmodel.Model.pid = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
                posmodel.Model.position = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                posmodel.dplist = """"I don't know what should I code here""""
                return View(posmodel);
            }
            else
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Here is my View:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model.position, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model.position, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model.position, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dplist, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.dplist, new SelectList(Model.dplist, "deptname", "deptname",Model.Model.did))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dplist, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model.pid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model.pid, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Model.pid, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

My model is

```
 public class PositionModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Position")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Position required.")]
        public string position { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Department")]
        public string dept { get; set; }
        public int pid { get; set; }

        //public List<DeptList> dplist { get; set; }
        public DeptList DeptList { get; set; }
        public int did { get; set; }
        public string deptname { get; set; }

    }

    public class DeptList
    {
        public int did { get; set; }
        public string deptname { get; set; }
    }
```

[output should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8djs.png)

Comment: why wouldn't yo use entity framework?

Comment: asp.net mvc is new to me, I find this way more comfortable for me because I came from vb.net and this coding style is easy for me to understand. But should I give it a try to use entity framework?

Comment: yes use entity framework. Its much better for your cv, plus this way is old school technology.

Answer (score 0):

```
  posmodel.dplist = new SelectList(dt.AsDataView(), "pid", "position");
```

Comment: no sir, btw departname is the one I want to display in dropdownlist posmodel.dplist = new SelectList(dt.AsDataView(), "deptname", "deptname"); ERROR=cannot implicity convert type system.web.mvc.selectlist to system.collection.genericlist. thank you for your reply I appreciate it sir.

Comment: btw sir, I update my question I put the output image. thanks

Comment: ok cool, change posmodel.dplist = new SelectList(dt.AsDataView(), "deptname", "deptname"); 

You need to see if you can convert dt.AsDataView() to a list i.e. try .ToList()

Comment: thanks for your reply. same error I tried these codes - posmodel.dplist = new SelectList(dt.AsDataView().ToList, "deptname", "deptname");  - posmodel.dplist = new SelectList(dt.AsDataView(), "deptname", "deptname").ToList; - posmodel.dplist = new SelectList(dt.AsEnumerable(), "deptname", "deptname").ToList;

Comment: if you like my answer mark it up please. expert in EF so can help.